# Using C with the TI EZ430-RF2500 dev chips

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

So what I am trying to do is receive a packet and print the payload to the serial port. Listening at the port is a python script that reassembles the payload and does some things with it.

Here is the code:

```
#include "mrfi.h"
int main(void)
{
  BSP_Init();
  MRFI_Init();
  //Initialize the serial port
  P3SEL    |= 0x30;
  UCA0CTL1  = UCSSEL_2;
  UCA0BR0   = 0x41;
  UCA0BR1   = 0x3;
  UCA0MCTL  = UCBRS_2;                     
  UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
  MRFI_WakeUp();
  MRFI_RxOn();
  __bis_SR_register(GIE+LPM4_bits);
}
//This is run when a packet is received
void MRFI_RxCompleteISR()
{
  uint8_t i;
  P1OUT ^= 0x02;
  mrfiPacket_t packet;
  MRFI_Receive(&packet);
  char output[] = {"                   "};
  for (i=9;i<29;i++) {
    output[i-9]='a';
    if (packet.frame[i]=='\r') {
      output[i-9]='\n';
      output[i-8]='\r';
    }
  }
  TXString(output, (sizeof output));
}
```

I send a packet with test data but nothing.  Anybody have any insights?  Also while just so you know I am learning C while I do this, so any pointers on design would also be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: How far does the data get? Do you know if the ISR is running at all? Are you checking all the error codes and status registers, and updating a status light?

Comment: Try asking on the msp430@yahoogroups.com mailing list, there are may people there that have experience with related issues.

Comment: What happens if you add `while (1) TXString("hello\r\n", 7);` at the end of `main()`?  Anything show up on the serial port? (that'll tell you if your serial routines are working anyway...)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Like I mentioned, I am very new to this I was basically given this by a professor and told to make it work, there are no error codes I can see and P1OUT ^= 0x02 toggles a light.

Comment: @Lindydancer I will do that, that you VERY much.
@Michael I added "while(1) TXString('a',1);" at the end and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Looks like a typo, it should be `"a"` with double quotes.

Comment: If you don't see a bunch of 'a' characters continually on the serial port with that, then your serial port routines have a problem. It could be a bug in the transmit routines, an initialization problem, a cable problem, or a configuration problem on the receiving end.  Or something else. But getting it so you can simply send data on the serial link and receive it is among the first things you need to solve.

Comment: Does one of your `_Init()` functions turn off the watchdog timer? If not, it is probably resetting the CPU before you can do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code isn't working, but here are some design hints as requested.

- Since this appears to be a hostless system, main() should most likely return void. I assume that you didn't post all of your code, as in a hostless there should also be an eternal loop in main().
- Remove all "magic numbers" from the code and replace them with #defined bitmasks or constants.
- Reduce all code inside interrupts to a minimum. The optimal interrupt only sets some flags.
- Don't use unspecified width (output[]) for arrays/strings. Embedded system design is about making things deterministic and fixed.
- Here is an example of another way to write that loop. As I have no idea what this program is supposed to do, replace the constant names with something that makes sense.

> ```
> uint8_t output[OUTPUT_N];
>
> memset(output, ' ', SPACES_N);
> output[OUTPUT_N - 1] = '\0';
>
> for(i=0; i < SOMETHING; i++)
> {
>   output[i + A_OFFSET] = 'a';
>
>   if(packet.frame[i + FRAME_OFFSET] == '\r')
>   {
>     output[i + CR_OFFSET] = '\r';
>     output[i + LF_OFFSET] = '\n';
>   }
> }
> ```